# ASP GridView not bind to select result

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, stored-procedures

I got stored function which returns query. In `ASP` project I got `GridView` which I bind to `SqlDataSource` element (it named `SqlDataProjectWells`).

So, when I try to call it there are error appears which says something like

> "error while trying to execute query"

But in pgAdmin select command works perfectly
[image]

Code calls on page load

```
void bindToTable(){
  SqlDataProjectWells.SelectCommand = "SELECT get_zonetable()";
  SqlDataProjectWells.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
 myGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Stored procedure code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_ZoneTable()
RETURNS SETOF RECORD
AS 
$$

BEGIN
    return QUERY SELECT "WELLS".well_name, "ZONES".id_zones, "ZONES".top, "ZONES".botom FROM "WELLS" LEFT JOIN "ZONES" ON "WELLS".well_id = "ZONES".id_well;
  /*RETURN;*/
    --return result_record;
END

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Whats wrong?!

**UPD:**

If I use stored procedure - there are such  error appears

> ERROR [0A000] Error while executing the query

If I use select like this

```
SqlDataProjectWells.SelectCommand = "SELECT \"WELLS\".well_name, \"ZONES\".id_zones, \"ZONES\".top, \"ZONES\".botom FROM \"WELLS\" LEFT JOIN \"ZONES\" ON \"WELLS\".well_id = \"ZONES\".id_well;"
```

It caused error which says

> A field or property with the name 'id_well' was not found on the
>   selected data source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, kinda solved problem this way. Stored procedure creates all_zones view which I use aftel in ASP code like `SqlDataProjectWells.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM all_zones";`

Stored procedure text

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_zones_view()
      RETURNS void AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE
    BEGIN

    execute 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "all_zones" AS SELECT "WELLS".well_name, "ZONES".id_zones, "ZONES".top, "ZONES".botom FROM "ZONES" JOIN "WELLS" ON "WELLS".well_id = "ZONES".id_well';


    END;
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

but I assume that it's not okay to do like that

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be calling DataBind on the GridView instead of the SqlDataSource?

Comment: @DanilGholtsman - The Select command of SQlDataSource returns the data you want.  Try binding THAT to the GridView.

Comment: ERROR [0A000] 
Error while executing the query

Comment: Comment above - it's what it says when I use stored procedure